# 'Doesn't have a release file' message upon Tweaks installation

Tags: release-juno, software-installation, ppa

Have installed elementary Juno on a new build. Trying to install Tweaks, below message pops up every time I open app center. Dont necessarily want tweaks now, just want to remove the following.

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file. W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you added a PPA that doesn't work with the current version of elementary. To delete it do `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily`

Comment: Problem solved. Many thanks Maccer

Comment: @Riotcode glad you found your answer :) Now please mark the question as answered, so that Maccer receives their points. Marking a question as "Answered" helps to keep the stack clean and encourages users to contribute. Thanks!